# Nonabelian group of order $p^n$ for every $p$ prime and $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Nonabelian group of order $p^n$ for every $p$ prime and $n \in \mathbb{N}$

My idea was to just create some sort of generalized dihedral group, that's what I called it at least, maybe it is.

$G = <x,y | x^{p^{n-2}}=1,y^{p^2}=1, y^{-1}xy=x^{-1}>$

Will this work?

Comment: Don't dihedral groups always have even order? What happens if $p$ is an odd prime?

Comment: Well, I don't know if what I gave should really have the word dihedral attached to it, haha. But from the presentation I gave it looks nonabelian of order $p^n$ but I want to make sure, I definitely could be wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I get that.

Comment: Your example doesn't work: since $y^{p^2}=1$, we should have $y^{-p^2}xy^{p^2}=1x1=x$ but instead you get by conjugating $p^2$ times $y^{-p^2}xy^{p^2}=x^{(-1)^{p^2}}=x^{-1}$, which means $x^2=1$ and hence $x=1$.  However, there is indeed some $d\not\equiv 1\pmod{p^{n-2}}$ such that $y^{-1}xy=x^d$ works, because of the existence of primitive root.

Comment: No that won't work for $p$ odd, because the automorphism of $\langle x \rangle$ induced by $x \mapsto x^{-1}$ has order $2$, and you need an automorphism of order a power of $p$. Also note that this is only possible for $n \ge 3$.

Comment: I think the most transparent example of a non-abelian group of order $p^3$ is the $p$-Sylow of $\mathrm{GL}_3(\mathbf{F}_p)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you written is close to a presentation for the semidirect product

$$(\Bbb{Z}/p^{n-2}\Bbb{Z})\rtimes(\Bbb{Z}/p^2\Bbb{Z}).$$

However, if $yxy^{-1} = x^k$ is the third relation, we need $k$ to be coprime to $p^2$. It’s not always true that $\gcd(p^{n-2}-1, p^2) = 1$, which is why your construction doesn’t quite work (as explained in the comments). That said, given your $p$ and $n$, such a $k\ne 1$ does always exist, so your construction is fixable.

Since it’s underlying set is the cartesian product, this group has order $p^{n-2}\cdot p^2 = p^n$. To see that this is a nonabelian group, note that $yxy^{-1} \ne x$.